# I have a question regarding "I am sorry"

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I would like to say

> **I'm sorry** that the item you needed for your brackets has been
>   discontinued.

Is this sentence correct?

Or should I say

> **I'm sorry.** The item you needed for your brackets has been
>   discontinued.

Can "I'm sorry" be used alone as a complete sentence?

Comment: It's a little more common to not personally apologize for something you have not caused and to say instead, "Unfortunately, the item you needed..."

Comment: The expression *I'm sorry that...* followed by some potentially disappointing news to the listener, is perfectly idiomatic. Though the whole question of apologising, and what it means to apologise, is a philosophical matter, that is more complicated than many people might think. And I agree with @Kristina.

Comment: You can write *I am* or *I'm* but not *I'am*.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Your comment differs from what I see often in movies and series. People often say "I'm sorry for your loss", even when they didn't have anything to do with the person who passed away.

Comment: @MeanGreen, you're right.  "I'm sorry for your loss" is an idiomatic expression that conveys condolences.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: more generally, you'll use "I'm sorry" if you want to show you sympathize with your interlocutor, even if you had nothing to do with the person's misfortune. That also counts for Customer service, if you want to appear closer to the person. Some may like it, some may not, the question is a whole debate as stated WS2.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can stand alone, as in, "I am sorry. The item you need for your brackets has been discontinued." 
"I'm sorry that the item you needed for your brackets has been discontinued" is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct and will work, although in my experience, the circumstance in which you would use them are slightly different.  If someone tried to order Item A, but you didn't have any, say

> I'm sorry.  That item is out of stock.

If someone tried to order Item A, but you were out of stock and they got angry about it (they really wanted that Item A)

> I'm sorry that Item A is out of stock.  Would you like Item B?

The difference being in the first example, you are informing them that Item A isn't available, and prefacing it with "I'm sorry" to soften the blow.  In the second, they already know it is not available and are upset about it.  You're using "I'm sorry" to apologize for the situation that is making them upset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either way is fine. Your second sentence is equivalent to

> I'm sorry to say (or *inform you*)  that the item you needed for your brackets has been discontinued.

This version and the stand alone *I'm sorry.* version mean you are offering an apology.

As Tofystedeth points out, your second sentence means that the speaker is apologizing for a situation his addressee is already upset about.

Another example:

> I'm sorry. We don't have any vanilla ice cream. Would you like to try one of our other 46 flavors?

or

> I'm sorry to say (or *inform you*)(that) we don't have any vanilla ice cream. Would you like to try one of our other 46 flavors?

or

> I'm sorry that we  don't have any vanilla ice cream. Would you like to try one of our  other 46 flavors?

Again the first two are equivalent: "softening the blow"  of the announcement that the place is out of item our flavor you want. The second is apologizing that the listener is already upset by this fact.